# Как работает функциональный стиль? JS

Tags: javascript, ооп, функции, переменные, функциональное-программирование

```
function Foo() {
    let buzz = 2;
    function Bar() {
        return buzz;
    }
    return Bar;
}
func = Foo(); // [Function: Bar]
func()        // 2
```

Как это работает? Почему `Bar()` "запоминает" `buzz` ?

Comment: Почитайте про замыкания в JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае используется замыкание:

По сути, создавая функцию, вы создаете новую область видимости. Когда функция выполняется, область видимости уничтожается вместе с переменными, поэтому переменные в функции инициализируются каждый раз заново.

```
function fn() {
  var a = 0;
  return ++a;
}
fn(); // 1
fn(); // 1
fn(); // 1
```

Но есть способ сохранить область видимости и ее переменные по завершению функции, для этого нужно вернут функцию. Фишка в том, что при создании функции, когда создается новая область видимости, так же запоминается и родительская область видимости ( грубо говоря на нее создается ссылка )

После окончания функции, результат-другая функция имеет ссылку на область функции, которую мы вызвали, поэтому ее нельзя удалить

```
function fn() {
 var a = 0;
 return fn1() {
   return ++a;
 }
}

const fn2 = fn(); // теперь у fn2 есть ссылка на область видимости fn
// поэтому GC, сборщик мусора, не может удалить эту область видимости

fn2(); // 1
fn2(); // 2
fn2(); // 3
```

Comment: я так понял нужно вернуть не другую а дочерную функцию .правильно?

Comment: ну да, функция должна быть создана в контексте родительской

Comment: спасибо    ........